# Angular JS Missing Required Controller error: Controller 'ngModel', required by directive can't be found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive:

```
directive('myDirective',
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                params: '=ngModel'
            },
            //template: '',
            templateUrl: '/myTemplate.html',
            controller: 'myController',
            link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModel) {
               // code.. 
            }
        };
    }
);
```

However when I use this directive, I get the following error in the console:
$compile:ctreq, with a hyperlink to the following message:
Missing Required Controller
error in component $compile
Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'myDirective', can't be found!

The error goes away if I use "template" instead of "templateUrl", and I do not wish to use the "template". 
This seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4603

Can anyone please suggest a **workaround**?
Edit: I am using ngModel because I want 2-way binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a parameter to a directive you can do it this way - what you have in your question does not look quite right to me.

```
<div my-directive my-param="foo"></div>


directive('myDirective',
    function() {
        return {
           restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                myParam: '='
            },
            //template: '',
            templateUrl: '/myTemplate.html',
            controller: 'myController',
            link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModel) {
               scope.myParam...
            }
       };
   }
```

);

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I want to achieve 2-way binding, hence I am using ngModel

Comment: I think that is what "=" should do so if you have a variable foo in your parent scope if should be updated if it is updated in the link function

Comment: DavidC, thanks for the clarification. I was mistaken in my understanding regarding 2-way binding in directives. I've created a jsfiddle to illustrate this, in case anyone else has the same question: http://jsfiddle.net/A8362/2/